# Asscess point cloud from Velodyne VLP16

Tags: ros, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,  I need the pointcloud from Velodyne VLP16. The author of velodyne drive  mentioned that "velodyne_pointcloud publishes its data using a custom PCL point definition: velodyne_pointcloud::PointXYZIR". Does that mean that is a topic? If so, after I did roslaunch "velodyne_pointclound VLP16_points.launch", nothing like that are in the topic list. Did I misunderstood something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246225/asscess-point-cloud-from-velodyne-vlp16/) by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the suggestion for the author to run ring_colors_nodelet which publishes velodyne_rings. However, velodyne_rings is still pointCloud2 instead of msg that contains x,y and z information of the point cloud from the Velodyne sensor.

---

Originally posted by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) with karma: 54 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0